# How to make a join in a hierarchical query

Tags: sql, tree, parent-child

I have these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Category
(
    curCategory VARCHAR2(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    parentCategory VARCHAR(50),

    CONSTRAINT check_cat CHECK (curCategory is not null),
    CONSTRAINT fk_category1 FOREIGN KEY(parentCategory) REFERENCES Category(curCategory)
);

CREATE TABLE Article
(
    name VARCHAR(50)
    artCategory VARCHAR(50),

    CONSTRAINT pk_article PRIMARY KEY(name),
    CONSTRAINT fk_artCategory FOREIGN KEY(artCategory) REFERENCES Category(curCategory)
);
```

What I want is something like this:

```
Select 
    level, curCategory, parentCategory 
from 
    Category 
join 
    article on artCategory = curCategory
start with curCategory = 'Clothes'
connect by prior curCategory = parentCategory 
order siblings by curCategory;
```

I want to print every article which is a clothes. So what I wanted to do is go through every child category including the category itself ('Clothes') and check if the article category matches the curCategory. But when I execute my query I get zero records.

Comment: Please add sample data and the expected result for this data to the question, preferably using [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) or [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2)

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you're using and it's version.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax looks like Oracle so - here's one option which shows what you might do.

Use `VARCAHR**2**` datatype, not `VARCHAR`. I shortened columns' length so that the output is easier to display. Also, there was a syntax error (a missing comma at the end of the article.name column declaration).

```
SQL> create table category (
  2    curcategory      varchar2(20) primary key,
  3    parentcategory   varchar2(20),
  4    constraint check_cat check ( curcategory is not null ),
  5    constraint fk_category1 foreign key ( parentcategory )
  6      references category ( curcategory )
  7  );

Table created.

SQL> create table article (
  2    name          varchar2(20),
  3    artcategory   varchar2(20),
  4    constraint pk_article primary key ( name ),
  5    constraint fk_artcategory foreign key ( artcategory )
  6      references category ( curcategory )
  7  );

Table created.
```

Some sample data:

```
SQL> select * from category;

CURCATEGORY          PARENTCATEGORY
-------------------- --------------------
clothes
trousers             clothes
shirts               clothes

SQL> select * from article;

NAME                 ARTCATEGORY
-------------------- --------------------
t-shirt              shirts
a-shirt              shirts
jeans                trousers

SQL>
```

According to that, the hierarchy should look like this:

```
clothes
  shirts
    t-shirt
    a-shirt
  trousers
    jeans
```

OK, let's make it so.

Out of two tables, using the WITH factoring clause (i.e. a CTE, common table expression), I'm UNION-ing those two tables in order to create a single parent-child source. Then, writing a hierarchical query is a simple matter.

```
SQL> with source as
  2    (select c.parentcategory parent, c.curcategory child
  3     from category c
  4     union
  5     select a.artcategory parent, a.name child
  6     from article a
  7    )
  8  select lpad(' ', 2 * level - 1) || child clothes
  9  from source
 10  start with parent is null
 11  connect by prior child = parent
 12  order siblings by child;

CLOTHES
------------------------------------------------------------
 clothes
   shirts
     a-shirt
     t-shirt
   trousers
     jeans

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: It works but than I will have problems with searching an article with a specific name as the name of article equals like a category ( select ... from source where child ='shirts'). If the user searches for the article 'shirts' the query will return the category shirt instead of the article name. is it possible to have article.name as an own column so when I check for the name i can use a.name ?